# View Creation using DDL trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, view, triggers, ddl

I am looking back at Oracle (11g) development after few years for my team project and need help. We are trying to implement a POC where any add/drop column will drop and recreate a corrosponding view. View refers to a Mapping table for producing its alias names and selection of columns.

My **solutions**:

--1. DDL Trigger that scans for Add Column, Drop Column -> Identifies Column Names -> Updates Field_Map table -> Drops View -> Creates View with Field_Map table alias names

Challenge: Received recursive trigger error because of View creation inside DDL

--2. DDL Trigger scans for Add Column, Drop Column -> -> Updates Field Map table -> Writes identified column names, tables to Audit_DDL table -> DML trigger on Audit_DDL table fires -> Disables DDL trigger (to avoid recursion) -> Drops view -> Creates view with Field_Map table alias names

Challenge: Received recursive trigger error. I think, it is still considering whole flow as one transaction. Separating create view under DML trigger didn't help.

so, I am thinking of **alternatives**:

--3. Store Trigger, Tables in Schema1 and View Schema2. I am expecting, this may avoid recursion since create view will now happen on schema2 and trigger is built on schema1.

--4. Create a Stored Procedure which scans for Audit_DDL entries (from #2) for tables, columns updated. Creates views and marks checked for processed Audit_DDL entries. Hourly job now runs this procedure.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance for helping me out!

Comment: When you say `View refers to a Mapping table for producing its alias names and selection of columns`, do you mean that the view was **created** by referring to this mapping table?  The view doesn't actually refer to the mapping table, does it?

Comment: That is correct Gerrat. View is built using execute immediate command, which will refer to field_map table just to provide right aliases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do DDL from a trigger, it would need to be asynchronous.  The simplest solution would be for the DDL trigger to submit a job using the `DBMS_JOB` package that would execute whatever DDL you want to do.  That job would not run until the triggering transaction (the `ALTER` statement) committed.  But it would probably run a few seconds later (depending on how many other jobs are running, how many jobs are allowed, etc.).  Whether you build the DDL statement you want to execute in the trigger and just pass it to the job or whether you store the information the job will need in a table and pass some sort of key (i.e. the object name) and let the job assemble the DDL statement is an implementation detail.

That being said, this seems like a really exceptionally poor architecture.  If you are adding or removing a column, that is something that should be going through a proper change control process.  If the change is going through change control, it should be easy enough to include the changes to the views in the same script.  And applications that depend on the views should be tested as part of the change control process.  If the change is not going through change control and columns are being added to or removed from views willy-nilly, you've got much bigger problems in the business process and you're very likely to cause one or more applications to barf in strange and wonderful ways at seemingly obscure points in time.

Comment: +1 especially for the comment about the exceptionally poor architecture.  Now I'm curious about the possible types of columns that could be removed or added willy nilly like this.

Comment: Idea here is not to change view interface at all so that downstream doesn't get the heat of changing many things on their end. I believe, it should work fine if there is a monitored addition to tables (and which is the case here), which will not cause any issues. Would like to know why you think it is not so ok design. Will keep you posted if I see any major hurdles (or accomplishments).

Comment: @user2989971 - If the goal is not to change the view interface, then it would not make sense to remove columns from the view which is what you are talking about in your question.  If you are doing a carefully monitored release, including the DDL to change the views as part of the change should be a trivial amount of effort.  It would make no sense to complicate the system by trying to automate that, you'd want the view DDL in your source control system anyway.