# PL SQL TRIGGER/PROCEDURE

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I created a table using Trigger and Procedure in PL/SQL, when I insert 10th records in student1 table, at the time trigger is fired and called procedure and create table automatically. When I run my query I get the following error:

```
Connecting to the database Spring.

ORA-04092: cannot COMMIT in a trigger
ORA-06512: at "EXIMUSER.CREATE_TABLE", line 13
ORA-06512: at "EXIMUSER.NEW_TABLE", line 10
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'EXIMUSER.NEW_TABLE'
ORA-06512: at line 3
12
test-trigger-procedure:
Process exited.
Disconnecting from the database Spring.
```

## Trigger

```
create or replace TRIGGER NEW_TABLE 
before INSERT ON student1
for each row
DECLARE v_rows NUMBER(10);
BEGIN
select count(*) into v_rows from student1;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_rows);
IF v_rows < 10 then
        insert into kaiser(ID,NAME) values(:new.myid,:new.name);
        commit;
    --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('test123'); 
    else
         EXIMUSER.create_table(:new.myid,:new.name);
         commit;
        End if;
END;
```

Procedure

```
create or replace PROCEDURE CREATE_TABLE (MYID IN NUMBER := NULL, 
inName IN VARCHAR2 := NULL ) 
AUTHID CURRENT_USER IS v_sql varchar2(200); 
table_found EXCEPTION; 
PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(table_found, -955); 
BEGIN 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('test-trigger-procedure:');
execute immediate 'create table fan3(id NUMBER(10),name varchar(20))';
--DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('test123');
END CREATE_TABLE;
```

Comment: What is confusing about the error message? Your trigger has a `commit` in it. That is not allowed. Your procedure is also doing DDL (dynamically) which implicitly commits; so that is also not allowed.

Comment: Thanks, If any other possible way create  table

Comment: [You can do it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20518281/266304), but you really shouldn't. That answer is about creating a database link but any DDL has the same issue. There are links from there to other approaches. But this is not a good idea, even while experimenting. Creating database objects on the fly means you are doing something wrong, the schema should really be static. Also, what happens when you insert the next record? It will try to create the table again - and it already exists. This isn't something you should ever want to do in the real world.

Comment: @AlexPoole: I don't think a DB Link is necessary. A procedure with an autonomous transaction should work as well, shouldn't it? But I agree this is a horrible idea

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - no, that's just an example of running any DDL; found that while looking for a duplicate. The onward links are about creating views. Maybe one of those is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

@mohamed,

Please find the rectified code below for your reference. Like my friends stated you cannot use commit inside the trigger unless it is an Independent transaction (Pragma AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION). Which in your case is not necessary at all. But since you have asked for it please find the code below.

Also creating a table is a very bad idea. Please check what will happen if the number of rows goes beyond 10? Oracle will try to create the same table each time a record is inserted(when the count of record goes more than 10) and would raise an exeception. Please avoid creating table inside a procedure going forward as it is a very bad idea.

## Trigger :

```
create or replace TRIGGER NEW_TABLE 
before INSERT ON student1
for each row
DECLARE 
PRAGMA autonomous_transaction;
v_rows NUMBER(10);
BEGIN
select count(*) into v_rows from student1;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_rows);
IF v_rows < 10 then
    insert into kaiser(ID,NAME) values(:new.myid,:new.name);
else
    create_table(:new.myid,:new.name); 
     End if;
END; 
/
```

## Procedure:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE CREATE_TABLE (MYID IN NUMBER := NULL,inName IN     VARCHAR2 := NULL ) 
AUTHID CURRENT_USER IS v_sql varchar2(200); 
c number;
table_found EXCEPTION; 
PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(table_found, -955); 
BEGIN 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('test-trigger-procedure:');
select count(1) into c from user_tables where table_name='FAN3';
if (c>0) then
dbms_output.put_line('Table already exists');
else
execute immediate 'create table fan3(id NUMBER(10),name varchar(20))';
END if;
END CREATE_TABLE;
```

Guys please note that the above code is not 100% efficient and nor will i recommend it. But the OP has asked how to create a table inside a procedure which is called by a trigger hence i am sharing the answer.

Comment: :sorry it could not be work... I reliazed trigger not support DDL statement (create table)... If any other way pls help me, If insert 10th row table create dynamically.

Comment: Have you tried the other code? Its working fine. I have changed it. Create table is even working. I have used pragma autonomous block for trigger,

Comment: @Mohamed I have updated the code. ALL YOUR NEEDS are not SATISFIED. Thank you.

Comment: yes create table is working fine, but call from trigger got below error message ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
ORA-06512: at "EXIMUSER.CREATE_TABLE", line 12
ORA-06512: at "EXIMUSER.NEW_TABLE", line 11
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'EXIMUSER.NEW_TABLE'
ORA-06512: at line 3

Comment: U need to grant privileges to your user. Tell me are you log in as sysdba or new user which you have created?

Comment: From sysdba session Try granting the privileges to your user. Like the below query.

grant create session, create any trigger to user_name;

Comment: Also you have used AUTHID CURRENT_USER in the procedure , if this command is used then it will run with the rights of whoever is calling it. Please grant the privileges to the user who is going to run the trigger or change the code accordingly. 

Try running the below sql query from sysdba and confirm if your query has been resolved:

Comment: grant create session, create any trigger to user_name;

Comment: user is newuser not sysdba user name eximuser and database name is spring

Comment: @Mohamed Connect yourself as sysdba and grant the privileges to the required users. like the one given below. Post which You can execute.

Comment: grant create session, create any trigger to newuser;
grant create session, create any trigger to eximuser;

Comment: follow the above mentioned link and then try to create and run the trigger. It should work. Thanks.